# What does <property name="hibernate.setup">true</property> in Confluence do?

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, configuration, confluence

I've got a question regarding a configuration property that I found in Confluence documentation towards the bottom of the page for setting up Hibernate: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-apache-tomcat-1867.html

```
<property name="hibernate.setup">true</property>
<!-- Assuming you could probably set it this to either true or false? -->
```

What does this config property do, exactly? I searched around in the official documentation for Hibernate but couldn't find anything describing it.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Given that this is the configuration file for Confluence (`confluence.cfg.xml`), the Hibernate docs aren't going to explain it.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Hibernate so I'm not yet aware of how Hibernate configurations work. I saw this property in the documentation and started wondering to myself on why have I never seen before... I didn't know (confluence.cfg.xml) was a configuration file for Confluence. I assumed it was most like a Hibernate configuration file since hibernate.dialect and hibernate.connection.datasource are Hibernate configurations. But, it makes more sense now on why I was pulling my hair out on trying to find it haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proerty says that the database connection is already configured. If you set this to false, you will go trought Confluence`s database connection creation wizzard.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! It is a custom configuration property setting used by Confluence setup? In other words, sort of like a indicator for Confluence to read to know whether or not the MySQL database has already been configured?

Comment: indicator to run or skip connection wizzard, and yes custom prop.